# How to select model constraints dynamically based on the obtained solution?

Tags: pyomo

I had a general pyomo question. In a concrete model (say) Ax = b; Cx < d; x > 0. here C is nxd (say n constraints).

Now If the solution obtained for C_n-1 is x'. Is there a way to reset the constraints to C_n or C'_n with in the same model and in the same run. i.e. I want to select the nth constraint depending on the solution of that iteration.

Is this possible? If yes could you please indicate how?

Comment: What do you mean by `select`?

Comment: I mean add the nth constraint dynamically in each constraint.  If the solution from C_n-1 belongs to space A than the nth constraint will be mx > n and if the solution belongs to space B the nth constraint will be mx < n (example).

Comment: Have you tried using a constraint list? It is an array of constraints that you can activate and deactivate at the same time.